# Google Maps API web service not providing accurate latitude longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I have used the code below to get latitude and longitude in C#.Net. But in some cases it provides the wrong latitude/longitude. For example, if I search "Braås skola Växjö Sweden" it provides [56.879004,14.805852] which is Växjö's latitude/longitude not what we searched! So how do we resolve this problem to get the exact latitude/longitude. This problem happens in many cases like "Braås förskola 44:an VÄXJÖ", "Björkens förskola VÄXJÖ".

```
private const String _googleUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=";
private const String _googleKey = "yourkey";
private const String _outputType = "csv";

private static Uri GetGeocodeUri(String address) {
    address = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address);
    return new Uri(String.Format("{0}{1}&output={2}&key={3}", _googleUri, 
address, _outputType, _googleKey));
}
public static Coordinate GetCoordinates(String address) {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = GetGeocodeUri(address);    
    String[] geocodeInfo = client.DownloadString(uri).Split(',');
    return new Coordinate(Convert.ToDecimal(geocodeInfo[2]), Convert.ToDecimal(geocodeInfo[3]));
}
```

Please help me get a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Request the [**places**](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearches)-service instead of geocoding.

Comment: But in places service daily limit is very low 1000 instead of 2500 in geocoding!

Comment: Maybe, but the thing you like to request is a place, not a location.